# What is the reason for Application getting log out unexpectedly?

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 10.1.3.3.0. The problem I am facing is: the application gets logged out unexpectedly at times and forcing the user to re-login. When I looked into log file (server.log), I could see this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlAttrsBinding$mySetEnabledThread.run(JUCtrlAttrsBinding.java:53)
```

Please help

Comment: The process ends because it found a NULL pointer when it needs to have data, a pointer that references a valid value.

Comment: 8 questions and not even one accepted answer. Why should I help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread on OTN](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=297913), it looks like bug 5642176, but it should be fixed in this version - the 'fixed bugs' list for 10.1.3.3 suggests so too. You may need to raise a TAR to get it looked at if you can't find a workaround.